# python: how to properly pass arguments to executable via commandline

Tags: python, command-line, parameters, subprocess

i'm trying to write a small python script, which will allow me to pass parameters to a command line dialog, in order to run a setup file.
i want to be able to pass parameters to the executable file, for example: "setup.exe --uninstall --delete-profile --force-uninstall"

i've tried to use the "os.system" module, as well as the "subprocess.call" module, but in both cases, the script doesn't work.
i'm not getting an error. instead, the script just ends, but the setup and\or the application files and folders are not deleted.
when i'm running the same commands manually (via the commandline), the application and relevant files are deleted.

here's the line of code:

```
subprocess.call('setup.exe --uninstall --delete-profile --force-uninstall', shell=True)
```

i think the problem is due to permissions (though i'm running the script via IDLE with admin rights) or with the "--" symbols, which separates the arguments (unfortunately, that's the format used by the setup file).

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Without more information we cannot really tell you what's going wrong. Try to manuall launch that command from a python terminal and report what error you get.

Comment: Did you try to pass your command as a list of args `['setup.exe', '--uninstall',...]` and use `shell=False` (the default).

Comment: @Bakuriu, when i'm running the "subprocess.call "command from python terminal, everything is working. the command is executed and the relevant files are deleted.
However, if i run the script via cmd ("python myscipt.py"), the script apears to be running, but the files are not deleted (again, no error. it just ends).

Comment: Maybe the IDE you are using is running the code from a different wroking directory? Consider using `os.chdir` to move to the correct directory before using `subprocess.call`, or specify the complete path for `setup.exe`.  Or maybe the IDE is performing some I/O redirection. Consider passing exlicitly the `stdout`/`stderr` parameters so that they write to a file and check those files.

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
subprocess.Popen(['hostname', '-f'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```

You can also add other parameters :

```
subprocess.Popen(['hostname', '-f', '-anotherparam', 'onemoreparam'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
```